# Globbing and grouping issue in a regex in sed

Tags: regex, sed, glob

I run the following [code](http://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/sysadmin-class/2008-fall/intermediate/week05_slides)

```
sed 's/\([^ ]+\) your \([^ ]+\)/ \2\1er/' < fail
```

The file fail is

```
fail your test
```

The above command gives me

```
fail your test
```

although it should give "testfailer".

The second and first globs `\2\1` should be at the start of the word "er".
This suggests me that the problem may be in the regexes in the search part.
However, they seem to be correct for me.

**Do you see any mistake in the code?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code does work when you escape the plus signs:

```
sed 's/\([^ ]\+\) your \([^ ]\+\)/\2\1er/' < fail
```

Comment: Ah, I see now.  + and () are considered extended regex features, so you enable them in 'basic' mode by backslashing them.  Good to know.

Comment: It seems that Leopard does not even have sed which has the quantifiers +, * and ?. I did not find Gnu Sed in MacPorts.

Comment: The name of Gnu Sed in MacPorts is gsed.

Answer (score 5):

Common or garden variety `sed` regex doesn't understand +.  Yeah, I know, how stupid is that.  So this is an equivalent, working version of your command line:

```
sed 's/\([^ ][^ ]*\) your \([^ ][^ ]*\)/ \2\1er/' < fail
```

Also works to request extended regex, in which case you ditch the backslashes on the parens:

```
sed -r 's/([^ ]+) your ([^ ]+)/ \2\1er/' < fail
```

Comment: Works in basic regex if you backslash the braces, in extended regex if you don't.

Comment: Backslashing the + in basic is less effort, though. :)